# python pandas - results overwritten when modifying column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a master dataset. I make a query to a SQL database to make slices of the master dataframe. Then I want to compare the results of my slices to the master, to add a new column to the master and record values there.

I have objects `master_df`, `zone1_df`, `zone2_df`. The size of `zone1_df` is 1671 rows. The size of `zone2_df` is 992 rows. As I said, `zone1_df` and `zone2_df` are subsets (slices) of the master. The master_df is huge (like 228,000 rows)

Now I get into pandas

I try and do the following. Basically I have an `id` column which contains the unique identifier for each row. I use the `id` column from `zone1_df` and compare that to the `id` column in `master_df`.

```
master_df['match'] = zone1_df['id'].isin(master_df['id'])
```

This results in `True` or `False` values in the `master_df['match']` column. So far, these result in correct values. If I run `master_df['match'].value_counts()` I get the following:

```
True    1671
```

This is correct. Now I use these true/false values to modify my `Zone` column:

```
master_df.loc[all_2019_parcels['match'] == True, 'Zone'] = 'Zone1'
```

I get the following values in the `Zone` columns when I run `master_df['Zone'].value_counts()`:

```
Zone1    1671
```

Now I try to do the same process again with `zone2_df`. Except I get results I don't understand.

```
master_df['match'] = zone2_df['id'].isin(master_df['id'])
master_df.loc[all_2019_parcels['match'] == True, 'Zone'] = 'Zone2'
```

Except now, my results are:

```
Zone2    992
Zone1    679
```

These add up to the size of `zone1_df`, which is 1671. But this makes no sense.

The desired result would be:

```
Zone2    992
Zone1    1671
```

Why are the results what they are? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure there is no overlap between Zone1 and Zone2? (i.e. how are the slices made?)

Comment: The result lets think that Zone2 is included in Zone1...